# Why is my logo looking weird in PDF when it looks fine InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf, export, image-quality

I have a brochure created in InDesign, the logo I am using on it is an AI vector. It looks normal in InDesign, but when I export to PDF it looks distorted. At 400% in PDF, it looks normal but when I zoom out to 100% it looks weird. Will this print normal? What is going on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What is it supposed to look like? What do you mean by "distorted" and "normal" and "weird"? What are your PDF export settings? What software are you using to view the PDF?

Comment: Print it on your laser printer and you'll see that it should look fine.

Answer (score 5):

It is a common Acrobat Reader preview bug where vertical letters (like `l`, `I` and `i`) will be displayed like this when converted to shapes (as in a logo). You notice the l's and i's on the right are fine, because that text is probably not outlined. However this is just a display glitch, if you print the artwork it will be fine. The issue is well known:

- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/570226
- http://support.serif.com/kb/a289/troubleshooting-when-i-publish-to-pdf-l-lower-case.aspx
- http://www.justskins.com/forums/what-s-up-with-68876.html

You need to edit your outlined vector logo and add some in-between points in any vertical shaped letter (`l`, `I` and `i`). Save your logo and relink in InDesign, export the PDF and there you go. :)

[image]

Comment: What do I do to fix this? Outline the text?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the logo, the text is outlined in Illustrator

Comment: Yes it only happens with outlined text. Normal (editable) text is not affected.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this? I didn't create the logo.

Comment: There is no real fix for it. There may be a setting in Acrobat's properties that allows you to display smooth graphics, but that will only affect your computer. We just explain to our clients that this is a display error in Acrobat, and tell them to zoom in or print the file to see for themselves. You could use a PNG instead of the vector graphic you have, but that's not advisable for printing.

Comment: Uhm, that's what i said yesterday but, actually trying this fix, it kind of seems to be working.

Comment: So It actually did print that way though. When we received the documents from the printer you can see the same problem. You're saying it should print normally?

Comment: **Thank you Lucian!** I've also known about this glitch for a while, and it drove me crazy while trying to create content for both print and screen! Our main logo has a series of "l"s and "i"s, and always looked like crap on screen, even in Acrobat DC. Adding vector points on the vertical paths in illustrator DOES work, make no mistake about it!! Thanks again! <3